# Does a Sidekiq worker know what time it was posted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Assuming a Sidekiq worker wasn't posted at the same time it started (i.e. via `perform_at` or `perform_in`), is the post time stored anywhere in the worker object? In other words, can a Sidekiq worker know what time it was posted? I could pass that value to `perform_at` but I'd rather not if it's already there.

Answer (score 2):

The created_at and enqueued_at times are stored in the job payload but not available from the worker instance.  They are accessible to middleware.